# Objectivity vs. Objectivism vs. Objectiveness

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, ambiguity

What are some clear-cut distinctions between objectivity, objectivism, and objectiveness?

Comment: please show your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referring to being *objective* in terms of independence or impartiality, one will almost always use *objectivity* as the noun, with *subjectivity* as its antonym. *Objectiveness* is a far less frequently used synonym, and one which not every dictionary recognizes.

You will encounter *objectiveness* somewhat more often in philosophical literature, where the term *objective* is in reference to the concept of an object in philosophy.

On the other hand, *[Objectivism](http://www.aynrand.org/site/PageServer?pagename=objectivism_intro)* is quite different entirely. It is used exclusively as a proper noun, the name for a philosophical system envisioned by the Russian-American novelist Ayn Rand. The claim to being an "objective" system derives from its atheist, empiricist, and rationalist tenets.